# Putting a const in a header

Tags: c++

From everything I am reading and testing, there is no way (without a preprocessor macro) to define a constant in a shared header and ensure that each TU is not creating its own storage for that constant.

I can do this:

`const int maxtt=888888;`

Which is the same exactly as:

`static const int maxtt=888888;`

And if this header is shared, it will work but each TU gets its own copy of `maxtt`. I could also do this, to prevent that:

`extern const int maxtt;`

But then I cannot define `maxtt` here; that must be done in a CPP to avoid linker error.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent that? It'll probably be optimized to just `888888` anyway, so don't think it'll increase code size.

Comment: Let me just note, for completeness, that your understanding is incorrect: three ways of providing constants in header files, so that storage is at worst allocated in one place, are discussed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14430581/464581). [@Kerrek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14430327/464581), currently selected as "solution", discusses why you might need those techniques, but curiously it then fails to even mention the techniques. The other answers, save my new one, are mainly misleading in giving the incorrect impression that your perception of the matter is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The whole point of making the constant value available to the compiler is so that the storage for it will be allocated where it is used (generally within an instruction), rather than somewhere else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the variable is constant, the fact that each TU gets its own copy is usually irrelevant.

In C++, constants at namespace scope are implicitly `static` for this reason. Often this allows for *better* code than if you only had a single instance with external linkage, since (if the variable is actually a constant expression) the constant can often be folded right into the usage site and doesn't need to be stored at all.

So unless you really need to take the address of the constant, or something like that, you should stick with the static version. (And as you already observed, you can force external linkage by adding `extern`.) Another reason may be that you're initializing dynamically and only want *one* call to the initializer:

```
// header:
extern int const n;

// one implementation:
int const n = init_function_with_side_effects();
```

The static construction (`int const n = init();` in the header) would cause the function to be called once in every TU.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP's problem, quote: "From everything I am reading and testing, there is no way (without a preprocessor macro) to define a constant in a shared header and ensure that each TU is not creating its own storage for that constant." Which impossibility is an incorrect impression -- and our task, to teach the OP the ways that it can be done.

Answer (score 9):

You write,

> “From everything I am reading and testing, there is no way (without a preprocessor macro) to define a constant in a shared header and ensure that each TU is not creating its own storage for that constant.”

Happily that’s ***incorrect***.

For a small integral value you can always just use an `enum`. The trade-off is that you can’t pass the address of an `enum` value, because it has no address. It’s pure value.

However, saving space for an integral value is a pretty meaningless thing to do, since it’s so small.

So, let’s consider a biggie thingy,

```
struct BiggyThingy
{
    unsigned char zeroes[1000000];
    BiggyThingy(): zeroes() {}
};
```

Now how can we declare a `BiggyThingy` constant in a header file and ensure a single one overall for the whole program?

### Using an inline function.

Well the simplest is this:

```
inline BiggyThingy const& getBiggyThingy()
{
    static BiggyThingy const theThingy;
    return theThingy;
}

static BiggyThingy const& biggyThingy = getBiggyThingy();
```

If you don’t want a reference taking up space (like a pointer) in each translation unit, then just use the function without the notation-simplifying reference.

### Using the template constant trick.

Here is another way to provide the constant, leveraging a special rule for templates instead:

```
template< class Dummy >
class BiggyThingyConstant_
{
public:
    static BiggyThingy const value;
};

template< class Dummy >
BiggyThingy const BiggyThingyConstant_<Dummy>::value;

typedef BiggyThingyConstant_<void> BiggyThingyConstant;
```

which can be accessed like

```
foo( BiggyThingyConstant::value )
```

Or if you want nicer notation you can add a reference per translation unit, as for the inline function solution.

### Disclaimer:

Code untouched by compiler.

But you get the ideas, I think. ;-)

Comment: This one line confused me: `BiggyThingy(): zeroes() {}` that is an initializer list but the ivar has no argument, does this "zero out" the ivar and its many elements

Comment: @Sebby: yes, it zeroes. It's a value initialization that reduces to zero initialization.

Comment: your `inline` example closely resembles a Singelton, yes? It's more or less a full "object" that exists just once for the entire program, regardless of where it is called.

Comment: @Sebby: Yes, in a technical sense. The technique of using a local static variable, which the function returns a reference to, is called a "Meyers' singleton", after Scott Meyers. But usually the term *singleton* implies a mutable object, so I would not use about this constant thing.

Answer (score 6):

This code generates a constant in the TU only if you apply any operation that requires the address of the constant.

```
static int maxtt = 888888;
int * pmaxtt = &maxtt; //address of constant requested.
```

This may work as well and avoids the linker problem (though it'll store `maxtt` in each TU if the address is requested):

```
constexpr int maxtt = 888888;
```

Avoid the `extern` construction as it can't be optimized.

Comment: Now it does answer the Q :) +1

Comment: I am missing information about toolchain used for that (compiler+linker at least).
I am not sure if C++ standard says anything about it as it goes beyond compilation, so results may heavily vary depending on tools used.

Answer (score 4):

If you're so worried about storage, use an enumeration:

```
enum { maxtt = 888888 };
```

Enumerators are scalar rvalues and hence do not require storage. It is illegal to say `&maxtt`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your understanding of the semantics are correct.

In practice, each translation unit might not get a copy of the storage for the integer. One reason is that the compiler might implement the value as a literal wherever it is referenced. The linker might also be smart enough to discard the storage if it finds it isn't referenced.

The compiler might not be free to use a literal for your constant. You might take a reference to that integer, or get a pointer to it. In that case, you need the storage -- and you might even need the cross-compiland uniqueness. If you take the address of your `const` symbol in each compilation unit, you might find that its different since each object will get a unique, static copy.

You might have a similar problem if you use an enum; your `const int` has storage, and you can take the address of that storage. You can't take the address of an enumerand until you store it someplace.

Comment: uh, the OP's "there is no way (without a preprocessor macro) to define a constant in a shared header and ensure that each TU is not creating its own storage for that constant" is very incorrect. so i wouldn't say that his understanding of the semantics in general, are correct. however, his understanding of a simple `const` declaration appears roughly correct.

Comment: That's true. (Fifteen characters.)